# River freezing conditions

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, weather, freezing

Quite uncommon -8°C here in Hamburg at the moment I write, and I thought: Surely our local rivulet is frozen over. In retrospect this was silly, the "rivulet" is 3rd order and has a very visible flow. Thus: Is there some rule of thumb to decide whether some waters will freeze at least at the top to give a continuous ice cap? The variables would be width, depth, flow speed, outside temperature and the duration of it. I'd guess the flow is most relevant.

Comment: The air in Hamburg has a temperature of −8 °C; however, the water of the Elbe has +4 °C.

Comment: @Loong: *Any* water has +4°C as a whole, loosely speaking. :-) (BTW, "local" meant "at my home place", i.e. the Tarpenbek feeding the Alster, not the Elbe. It has to be brass monkeys until you see ice on the Elbe...)